# How can I copy the body of different JSON files and write them all to one file with Python?

Tags: python, json, avro

I'm trying to parse some Avro files (which contain JSON) in my file directory and get the "Body" data that I can then write to a single CSV file, named "AllBodyData.csv".

I found this example of a function that parses all the body fields and creates different CSV files based on their id inside the JSON body.

This is being looped inside the main function with a `for file in file_list`

```
def processBlob(filename):
    reader = DataFileReader(open(filename, 'rb'), DatumReader()) #Convert avro to json
    dict = {}
    for reading in reader:
        parsed_json = json.loads(reading["Body"])
        if not 'id' in parsed_json:
            return
        if not parsed_json['id'] in dict:
            list = []
            dict[parsed_json['id']] = list
        else:
            list = dict[parsed_json['id']]
            list.append(parsed_json)
    reader.close()
    for device in dict.keys():
        filename = os.getcwd() + '\\' + str(device) + '.csv'
        deviceFile = open(filename, "a")
        for r in dict[device]:
            deviceFile.write(",".join([str(r[x]) for x in r.keys()])+'\n')
```

Credit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-python#create-a-python-script-to-read-your-capture-files

What I'm trying to achieve is to write all the data in only one single file, and not separate them according to their ID.

I thought of something like this

```
def processBlob(filename):
    reader = DataFileReader(open(filename, 'rb'), DatumReader())
    dict = {}
    for reading in reader:
        parsed_json = json.loads(reading["Body"])
            list = dict[parsed_json]
            list.append(parsed_json)
    reader.close()
    for device in dict.keys():
        filename = os.getcwd() + '\\' + AllBodyData + '.csv'
        deviceFile = open(filename, "a")
        for r in dict[device]:
            deviceFile.write(",".join([str(r[x]) for x in r.keys()])+'\n')
```

If I'm not allowed to use `dict = {}` because it's not hashable, then how should I proceed?

Comment: why not load it into proper `json` using an `avro` library that loads the string in to proper format

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see values in variables - it is called `"print debuging"`. Maybe you shouldn't use code from other source but write it all from scratch and then you will know what this code is doing. And write code step by step - first only read file and display it, next cut element which you need, next add it to some list, and finally save it in one file.

Comment: in this code I see one big mistake - in first loop you create `list = ...`  again and again but you never add `parsed_json` to `dict` which you use later to write data . You shoyuld rather use `dict[devide] = parsed_json`

Comment: if you want to save in one file then use then same name all time `filename = "AllBodyData.csv"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only issue is that the original code chunk makes separate files and you want a single file, then you can just change the bottom part of the original snippet to the following:

```py
filename = os.getcwd() + '\\' + 'all_data' + '.csv'
deviceFile = open(filename, "a")
for device in dict.keys():
    for r in dict[device]:
        deviceFile.write(",".join([str(r[x]) for x in r.keys()])+'\n')
```

So the full code snippet would look like this:

```py
def processBlob(filename):
    reader = DataFileReader(open(filename, 'rb'), DatumReader()) #Convert avro to json
    dict = {}
    for reading in reader:
        parsed_json = json.loads(reading["Body"])
        if not 'id' in parsed_json:
            return
        if not parsed_json['id'] in dict:
            list = []
            dict[parsed_json['id']] = list
        else:
            list = dict[parsed_json['id']]
            list.append(parsed_json)
    reader.close()
    filename = os.getcwd() + '\\' + 'all_data' + '.csv'
    deviceFile = open(filename, "a")
    for device in dict.keys():
        for r in dict[device]:
            deviceFile.write(",".join([str(r[x]) for x in r.keys()])+'\n')
```

On a side note, the snippet from Microsoft is really hard to read because they do things like `dict = {}` which overwrites the built-in name `dict`. Python allows you to do this, but it makes the code very difficult to understand. I would suggest not doing that in your own code.